# String search algorithm that returns recursive matches - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, search, full-text-search, string-search

The Rabin-Karp search algorithm is working fine but can anyone help to guide me in modifying it to a recursive search? http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/RabinKarp.java.html .
For example:

```
 *  **pattern:** rar
 *  **text:**    abacadabrararbracabrarararacadabrabrarbracad 
 *  **match1:**          rar               
 *  **match2:**            rar
 *  **match3:**                     rar
 *  **match4:**                       rar
 *  **match5:**                         rar
 *  **match5:**                                     rar
```

Are there other faster algorithm for recursive text matching searches?

**SOLUTION**

Add external library from http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/ to build path. The code below will return all the starting position of the matches. inclusive of embedded ones like match1 and match2.

```
import com.eaio.stringsearch.BNDM;

String pattern = "rar";
String text = "abacadabrararbracabrarararacadabrabrarbracad";

// Loop through text to get starting position of matched pattern.
List<Integer> matchPoint =new ArrayList<Integer>();
int slice = -1;
while (slice<text.length()){
    slice+=1;
    com.eaio.stringsearch.BNDM result = new BNDM();
    int pos = result.searchString(text, slice, pattern);
    if (pos != -1) {
        slice = pos;
        matchPoint.add(pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have experience converting iterative code into recursive code, for a generic case that is?

Comment: nope, usually i simply put `pattern` it into a function and call the search until the function replies end of `text`

Comment: Well you are somewhat in the right track. The idea is to break the problem that one iteration solves into a two or more sub problems and then solve those with another recursive call. That is the basic principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is. I will not recommend using Rabin-Karp in case of searching a small pattern in string. KMP i.e Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm takes linear time and linear additional memory and can return all the matches without the case of collisions which are nag when dealing with Rabin-Karp. Please read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) for it. This algorithm is a bit harder to understand, but shorter to code and once you get it right you feel very satisfied.

Comment: I tried running this KMP module into my code and i ended up with insufficient memory problem. http://www.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/fmi/logic/vboutchkova/sources/KMPMatch_java.html . Is there any other simple yet memory saving methods for string search, i've tried the BNDM from http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/ but it's a little too long to recode and my instructions for my project was to keep string search simple yet time/memory unconsuming. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a bit troublesome -if you get out of memory for an algorithm that takes twice as much memory than the input itself (or even significantly less if the pattern is smaller than the string to search in). Probably it is more likely that you have bad settings of the VM of java. Now I am even more urged to help you as I found out we come from the same university :P

Comment: =) Boris, are you from NTU or UdS ? hahaha. I've made the Rabin-Karp recursive and it goes into out-of-memory problems too. I've solved the problem by implementing BNDM algo. But it's still not as fast as if i use the API from http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/

Answer (score 1):

For longer patterns, the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) or variants like [Horspool's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore-Horspool_algorithm) are generally faster. The Boyer-Moore algorithm isn't particularly well suited for large alphabets. If the text can be the full Unicode range, it would use a rather large shift table, but if the text is ASCII or latin1, the extra space for the lookup tables  is small. For large alphabets, I also recommend KMP.